# Dump subtitle from AVSubtitle in the file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, subtitle

In FFMPEG sofftware, AVPicture is used to store image data using data pointer and linesizes.It means all subtitles are stored in the form of picture inside ffmpeg. Now I have DVB subtitle and I want to dump picture of subtitles stored in AVPicture in a buffer. I know these images subtitles can be dump using for, fopen and sprintf. But do not know how to dump Subtitle.I have to dump subtitles in .ppm file format.

Can anyone help me to dump picture of subtitles in buffer from AVSubtitle .

Comment: AVPicture is deprecated long ago. I think you mean AVFrame instead. And possibly update your ffmpeg installation first.

Comment: The data is not stored in AVFrame format. The AVPicture interface was removed in ffmpeg 5.0, after having been deprecated for several years, but the storage format remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This process looks complex but actually very simple.
`AVSubtitle` is generic format, supports text and bitmap modes. Dvbsub format afaik bitmap only and the bitmap format can be differ like 16color or 256color mode as called `CLUT_DEPTH`.
I believe (in current ffmpeg) the bitmaps stored in `AVSubtitleRect` structure, which is member of `AVSubtitle`.
I assume you have a valid `AVSubtitle` packet(s) and if I understand correctly you can do these and it should work:
1) Check `pkt->rect[0]->type`. The pkt here is a valid `AVSubtitle` packet. It must be type of `SUBTITLE_BITMAP`.
2) If so, bitmap with and height can be read from `pkt->rects[0]->w` and `pkt->rects[0]->h`.
3) Bitmap data itself in will be `pkt->rects[0]->data[0]`.
4) CLUT_DEPTH can be read from `pkt->rects[0]->nb_colors`.
5) And CLUT itself (color table) will be in `pkt->rects[0]->data[1]`.

With these data, you can construct a valid `.bmp` file that can be viewable on windows or linux desktop, but I left this part to you.

**PPM Info**

First check this info about PPM format:
https://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~soni/cs35/f13/Labs/extras/01/ppm_info.html

What I understand is PPM format uses RGB values (24bit/3bytes). It looks like to me all you have to do is construct a header according to data obtained from `AVSubtitle` packet above. And write a conversion function for dvbsub's indexed color buffer to RGB. I'm pretty sure somewhere there are some ready to use codes out there but I'll explain anyway.
In the picture frame data Dvbsub uses is liner and every pixel is 1 byte (even in 16color mode). This byte value is actually index value that correspond RGB (?) values stored in Color Look-Up Table (CLUT), in 16 color mode there are 16 index each 4 bytes, first 3 are R, G, B values and 4th one is alpha (transparency values, if PPM doesn't support this, ignore it).

I'm not sure if decoded subtitle still has encoded YUV values. I remember it should be plain RGBA format.

**encode_dvb_subtitles** function on ffmpeg shows how this encoding done. If you need it.
https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/a0ac49e38ee1d1011c394d7be67d0f08b2281526/libavcodec/dvbsub.c

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry to say but I know all the things that you told me. Main thing is construct a valid .bmp file that can be viewable in linux desktop. I know all the functionality of data and linesize theoritical. But I do not how to print . Please also help in this to construct a .bmp file.

Comment: With these all data I will create .bmp file but if I want to create .ppm format file. How can I achive this.

Answer (score 0):

As this is where I ended up when searching for answers to how to create a thumbnail of an AVSubtitle, here is what I ended up using in my test application. The code is optimized for readability only. I got some help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60551861/2501078) which had some sample code.

Using `avcodec_decode_subtitle2()` I get a `AVSubtitle` structure. This contains a number of rectangles. First I iterate over the rectangles to find the max of *x + w* and *y + h* to determine the width and height of the target frame.

The color table in data[1] is RGBA, so I allocate an `AVFrame` called *frame* in `AV_PIX_FMT_RGBA` format and shuffle the pixels over to it:

```c++
struct [[gnu::packed]] rgbaPixel {
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t a;
};

// Copy the pixel buffers
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sub.num_rects; ++ i) {
    AVSubtitleRect* rect = sub.rects[i];
    for (int y = 0; y < rect->h; ++ y) {
        int dest_y = y + rect->y;

        // data[0] holds index data
        uint8_t *in_linedata = rect->data[0] + y * rect->linesize[0];

        // In AVFrame, data[0] holds the pixel buffer directly
        uint8_t *out_linedata = frame->data[0] + dest_y * frame->linesize[0];
        rgbaPixel *out_pixels = reinterpret_cast<rgbaPixel*>(out_linedata);

        for (int x = 0; x < rect->w; ++ x) {
            // data[1] contains the color map
            // compare libavcodec/dvbsubenc.c
            uint8_t colidx = in_linedata[x];
            uint32_t color = reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(rect->data[1])[colidx];

            // Now store the pixel in the target buffer
            out_pixels[x + rect->x] = rgbaPixel{
                .r = static_cast<uint8_t>((color >> 16) & 0xff),
                .g = static_cast<uint8_t>((color >>  8) & 0xff),
                .b = static_cast<uint8_t>((color >>  0) & 0xff),
                .a = static_cast<uint8_t>((color >> 24) & 0xff),
            };
        }
    }
}
```

I did manage to push that AVFrame through an image decoder to output it as a bitmap image, and it looked OK. I did get green areas where the alpha channel is, but that might be an artifact of the settings in the JPEG encoder I used.