# AVSubtitleRect DVBSub format explanation

Tags: c, ffmpeg, bitmap, subtitle

I am trying to convert the DVBSub data in AVSubtitle to RGB format but it doesn't seem to be working. I am just getting random colours out.

Here's the code:

```
/* rects comes from AVSubtitleRect type elsewhere*/

int bw = rects[0].w;
int bh = rects[0].h;
uint32_t colour;
uint32_t *bitmap;
int r, g, b;

/* Give it some memory */
bitmap = malloc(bw * bh * sizeof(uint32_t));

for (int y = 0; y < bh; y++) 
   {
        for (int x = 0; x < bw; x++) 
        {
            /* data[0] holds index data */
            const uint8_t index = rects[0]->data[0][y * bw + x]; 

            /* data[1] holds colours - get colour from index */
            colour = rects[0]->data[1][4 * index];

            r = (colour >> 16) & 0xFF;
            g = (colour >>  8) & 0xFF;
            b = (colour >>  0) & 0xFF;

            /* construct bitmap pixel by pixel (24 bit RGB) */
            bitmap[y * bw + x] = r << 16 | g << 8 | b;
        }
    }
```

There is some information here [Dump subtitle from AVSubtitle in the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54125207/dump-subtitle-from-avsubtitle-in-the-file) but I am not sure I am understanding it correctly.

I am sure that I am getting the data correct and text based subtitles look fine. Not quite sure what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DVBSub rectangles uses indexed color bitmap. Either 2, 16 or 256 colors per pixel used.
Having said that almost always these rectangles uses 16 (4bit) indexed color format.
And yet single pixel takes whole 8bit (4bit+4bit zeros).
CLUT (color look up table) uses full 32 bit ARGB format (yes with Alpha channel for transparency). So for 16 color format, CLUT size is 64 bytes (16*4).

Hope these helps.